# Wordpress - display media on page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

A client wants a full page full of PDFs, and an option to be able to assign a PDF to a page automatically.

For example, conveyancing.pdf would appear on downloads.php (along with several others), but also have an option to tick 'yes I want this PDF to also feature on the conveyancing page'. Is this possible, and if so how would you approach it?

If I made a custom post type for the pdfs, is there an option to list all the pages it can appear on, like you'd tick categories but this would be 'pages'?

Answer (score 0):

"a full page full of PDFs"?

Do you mean a page with links to multiple PDFs on the server?

Chrome / firefox and maybe IE have a built in PDF viewer and there is an option to save, download or print.

[How to Upload & Link to a PDF file in WordPress](https://www.geckodesigns.com/tutorials/upload-link-pdf-file-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right, you want to upload pdf files from the admin panel and attach them to pages. 
since you didn't specify what you already done, i will start from the beginning.

I've done this before on some project, i needed to let a client upload documents to post type page and custom post types. you can create a new custom fields on your code if you like too but i think if you'r out of time, you can installed for example the [WCK](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/) plugin because besides of options like create new custom post types or taxonomy easily, it also let you create custom fields with repeater (which is not freely in every other good custom field creator plugin).

create with the plugin a new meta box and then the document field (you will need to do it for each post type). after that, you will see the new custom field on the post type you've been chosen, upload a document for the test and on you theme code call to get the field, check [this](http://www.cozmoslabs.com/docs/wordpress-creation-kit-documentation/upload/) link to get the detailed instructions.

after it will work for you you will want to add an option to attach some documents to other page by some checkbox right? you can create another custom field (checkbox) under the same meta box so it will Appear with every document field and then get the value on the code theme to check if it checked or not, that way you can control what documents will appear in the template you want to get by the checked checkbox of document ("show this document in other templates").

the problem with this should be how to get the id's of the pages who have the selected checkbox to the current page, i didn't try it but maybe you call all the pages with WP_Query and in the array use the specific post type you like and the [custom field parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to get only the pages with the check box, after that you can run a foreach on the array and use a condition to check for the value of each page checkbox, if it true get the custom field (document) and in the place to insert the post id use the id of the post in the foreach so it need to bring you the specific document. i would love to hear if it worked for you, good luck!